# Pause bash script until signal of another one

Tags: bash

What is the shortest way to sleep a bash script at a certain location until another script wakes it up to continue it's job?
Mayby using `flock -u ..` or blocking read on a pipe ?

Comment: The read-from-a-pipe approach is a little less trouble here -- advisory locks are held on a FD, not a file, so the thing that's releasing them has to *hold* them until they're released; a `flock()` advisory lock can't be held without some running program with an open file descriptor holding it.

Comment: That said, what's the larger context? One almost wonders if your situation might call for coprocesses, but can't assess if they're appropriate without more details (f/e, whether the processes have any kind of direct relationship with each other).

Comment: ...it's also possible to rely on a signal to interrupt a `sleep`, but that's more error-prone than is probably good to encourage.

Comment: cant you use file locks? and while loop when file lock(s) exists?

Comment: Killing `sleep` is cumbersome as it requires the messaging of the PID to the other script.

Comment: Waiting by `flock` has the problem that it is not easy to flock a section of an bash script if not wrapped by another bash script file.

Answer (score 0):

Say `scriptA` sleeps and waits for being waken up by `scriptB`.

One way is, in `A`, before you sleep, write the pid to some file say `scriptA.pid` then falling in sleep.

When `B` is running, at the right moment, you can read the `scriptA.pid` file, to get the pid of `A`, then do `pkill -P pidofA sleep` thus, the sleep sub-process will be killed, and `A` will continue its execution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of named pipes (fifo).  scriptA.sh:

```
pipe='/tmp/mypipe'
mkfifo "$pipe"

echo "$0 going to sleep..."

# Should block
read < "$pipe"

echo "$0 continuing"
```

scriptB.sh

```
pipe='/tmp/mypipe'
mkfifo "$pipe"

echo "$0 waking other process"

# might block
echo > "$pipe"

echo "$0 exiting"
```

You will get a `mkfifo: /tmp/mypipe: File exists` from the second `mkfifo`, if that bothers you then test for existence first (`-e "$pipe"`).  This does not tidy-up (`rm`) the fifo, not sure where that should go because timing of the application is critical to where you put that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the inter process signals: the `kill` command should be used to send a signal to a process using its pid.

The `SIGSTOP` signal stops the execution of the process.

The `SIGCONT` signal resumes the process execution.

The example script below:

- stores the pid of the process in a file.
- the script sends to its own process the `SIGSTOP` signal (`$$` is the pid of the current bash process).

Hopefully, another process will resume the execution.

Give a try to this:

```
#!/bin/bash --

printf "%s" $$ > /tmp/aScript.pid

kill -STOP $$ # STOP the execution here

# execution continues here when the SIGCONT signal is received
printf "script %s:  received the SIGCONT signal\n" $$
```

Test in a terminal:

```
$ ./aScript.sh &
[1] 26444

$ kill -CONT $(cat /tmp/aScript.pid)
script 26444:  received the SIGCONT signal
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1st method

The running script can stop itself -

```
$: cat flagfile
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo $$ > /tmp/flagfile.pid
kill -STOP $$
date

$: ./flagfile &
[1] 24679

$: ps -fu $LOGNAME | grep 'flagfile$'
P2759474  24679  24521  0 13:29 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/bin/bash ./flagfile
[1]+  Stopped                 ./flagfile
```

Then any other script can restart it.

```
$: kill -CONT $(</tmp/flagfile.pid)
$: Wed Dec 12 13:36:01 CST 2018
```

That last line gave me back a prompt before the background process managed to output the date. :)

> 2nd method

If a delay is ok, you can have a trap break it out.
This isn't *totally* stopping the script, but you can set the delay and make it as freindly as you have leeway to wait for it to wake up.

```
$: cat flagfile
#!/usr/bin/bash
trap 'loop=0' USR1
loop=1
delay=2
echo $$ > /tmp/flagfile.pid
while (( loop )); do sleep $delay; done
date

$: ./flagfile &
[1] 25018
$: ps -fu $LOGNAME | grep 'flagfile$'
P2759474  25018  24521  0 13:42 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/bin/bash ./flagfile
```

Wait as long as you like....

```
$: kill -USR1 $(</tmp/flagfile.pid)
$: Wed Dec 12 13:42:43 CST 2018
[1]+  Done                    ./flagfile
```

Comment: Note others have mentioned the passing of the pid can be problematic. I have used a standard name, but that means only one instance can be running...