# How to read a file that's been overwritten multiple times?

Tags: ruby, bash, parallel-processing, buffer

I have a bash script that keeps taking screenshots, as fast as possible, it normally takes 1-2ms per run.

I also want to have a separate process, running constantly on another thread, that will take said screenshot files and do something with them (crop, read, whatever).

Sometimes I can run both side by side just fine, but sometimes process B is trying to read the file that process A is still writing to.

How to approach this?

I imagine something like a cache/copy/buffer will help, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you need *all* of them whole? You might try writing them as individual filenames, but that's going to use a lot of space and need a cleanup step in there somewhere.... You might also try some IPC like signals or semaphores.

Comment: c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53745465/pause-bash-script-until-signal-of-another-one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remembered about file locks and they are exactly what I need for this.

While taking the screenshots I will use UNIX's [flock](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html) (with an exclusive lock) and while reading the files I will use Ruby's [File#flock](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/File.html#method-i-flock) with a shared lock.

This should do it!

Answer (score 1):

I made a couple simple files that do stuff before and after a control volley - in this case, just report which file is at which point in the loop, so I literally just symlinked it to a second name. I called them a & b.

```
$: cat a

for a in 1 2 3  
do echo "$0 $a before: $(date)"
   kill -CONT -1 # NOTE: sends the signal to ALL procs in group
   kill -STOP $$
   echo "$0 $a AFTER:  $(date)"
done
kill -CONT -1
```

b is the same file, just another name.

run both. Use a `wait` to clean up the prompt at the end.

```
$: ./a;./b;wait
./a 1 before: Mon, Aug 10, 2020 12:56:41 PM

[1]+  Stopped                 ./a
./b 1 before: Mon, Aug 10, 2020 12:56:41 PM

[2]+  Stopped                 ./b
./a 1 AFTER:  Mon, Aug 10, 2020 12:56:41 PM
./a 2 before: Mon, Aug 10, 2020 12:56:41 PM

[1]+  Stopped                 ./a
./b 1 AFTER:  Mon, Aug 10, 2020 12:56:41 PM
./b 2 before: Mon, Aug 10, 2020 12:56:41 PM

[2]+  Stopped                 ./b
./a 2 AFTER:  Mon, Aug 10, 2020 12:56:41 PM
./a 3 before: Mon, Aug 10, 2020 12:56:41 PM

[1]+  Stopped                 ./a
./b 2 AFTER:  Mon, Aug 10, 2020 12:56:42 PM
./b 3 before: Mon, Aug 10, 2020 12:56:42 PM

[2]+  Stopped                 ./b
./a 3 AFTER:  Mon, Aug 10, 2020 12:56:42 PM
[1]-  Done                    ./a
./b 3 AFTER:  Mon, Aug 10, 2020 12:56:42 PM
[2]+  Done                    ./b
```

This throws a lot of trash to stderr, but you can redirect that.

```
$: { ./a;./b;wait; } >log 2>err
```

Maybe it will offer some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is to write the file in a different folder on the same drive, or with a different extension, so that you can easily exclude it from the selection (for example, instead of `images/foo.jpg`, write to `images/foo.jpg.temp`, and list with `*.jpg`), then use atomic move when it is finished (`mv images/foo.jpg.temp images/foo.jpg`).